# Алгоритм движения. PHP

Tags: php, рекурсия

В общем вроде всё просто, но не очень =)
Задача следующая - есть сетка NxM, и рекурсия ходит по клеткам. Как сохранять направление движения? В данный момент приоритет "вверх вправо вниз влево", т.е. попав на следующую клетку, например справа, опять будет попытка пойти вверх, а нужно продолжить движение влево, и если там тупик, тогда уже по остальным.
Грубо говоря - есть четыре условия if, и мне нужно начинать не с первого if, но выполнить все 4.

Comment: Неправильно логику написал вот и не туда идет.
У тебя должна быть функция которая смотрит наперёд, можно ли двигаться в том же направлении, если да то идти туда (передать текущее направление), если нет, то передать в рекурсию следующее направление
0 - вверх
1 - вправо
2 - вниз
3 - влево

Comment: передать то можно, но если тупик во все направления то до посинения будет передавать следующее направление, а счетчик дополнительным параметром неохота передавать

Comment: тупик во все направления? если ты туда зашел, то и вернуться сможешь обратным ходом по этому алгоритму

Comment: А в чем вообще задача? пройти все ячейки как бы естественным способом, типа змейкой? или нужен какой-то особенный маршрут, в твоем примере это же по кругу 4 ячейки проходят.

Comment: никто ничего внятного так и не предложил, оставил как есть :)

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того что написано, вверх вправо вниз влево - это ходить по кругу. Выполняйте итерации пока соблюдается условие, как только следующую итерацию невозможно сделать переходите в следующий цикл

Comment: Добавьте может пример...

Answer (score 0):

> Грубо говоря - есть четыре условия if, и мне нужно начинать не с первого if, но выполнить все 4.

Замени 4 if'а на 4 while'а.